# Fill axis background in pgfplots except a given shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to fill the background of a plot axis except in a given circle. I do not want to fill the circle in the plot with white since this plot will be reused in different presentations where the background might not be white.

I tried the following code without success.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        xmin=-4,%
        xmax=2.5,%
        ymin=-4,%
        ymax=2.5,%
        axis equal image,%
        xlabel={$x_1$},%
        ylabel={$x_2$},%
        axis background/.style={fill=black!10,even odd rule, insert path={(0,0) circle[radius=2^0.5]}},%
    ]
        \draw(axis cs:0,0) circle[radius=2^0.5];
        \draw[-latex] (axis cs:-1,-1) -- (axis cs:-3,-3) node[below right] {$\nabla c_1(x^{\ast})$};
        \draw[-latex] (axis cs:-1,-1) -- (axis cs:-2,-2) node[below right] {$\nabla f(x^{\ast})$};
        \addplot[red,mark=*,only marks] coordinates {(-1,-1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Did anyone succeed in this talk?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should always post compilable code, or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At that point, PGFPlots does not use `axis:cs` while it does inside `axis`.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-4, xmax=2.5,
ymin=-4, ymax=2.5,
axis equal image,
xlabel={$x_1$}, ylabel={$x_2$},
axis background/.style={fill=black!10, even odd rule, insert path={let \p1=(axis cs:0,0), \p2=(axis cs:0,{sqrt(2)}), \n1={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)}, in (\p1) circle[radius=\n1]}},
]
\draw(0,0) circle[radius=sqrt(2)];
\draw[-latex] (-1,-1) -- (-3,-3) node[below right] {$\nabla c_1(x^{\ast})$};
\draw[-latex] (-1,-1) -- (-2,-2) node[below right] {$\nabla f(x^{\ast})$};
\addplot[red,mark=*, only marks] coordinates {(-1,-1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Filled graph except for a central circle]

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.15}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        xmin=-4,%
        xmax=2.5,%
        ymin=-4,%
        ymax=2.5,%
        axis equal image,%
        xlabel={$x_1$},%
        ylabel={$x_2$},%
        axis background/.style={even odd rule, insert path={(0,0) circle[radius=2^0.5]}},%
 ]  
    
        \path[draw,red,name path=L1](current axis.south west) rectangle (current axis.north east);
        \draw[name path=L2](axis cs:0,0) circle[radius=2^0.5];
        \draw[-latex] (axis cs:-1,-1) -- (axis cs:-3,-3) node[below right] {$\nabla c_1(x^{\ast})$};
        \draw[-latex] (axis cs:-1,-1) -- (axis cs:-2,-2) node[below right] {$\nabla f(x^{\ast})$};
        \addplot[red,mark=*,only marks] coordinates {(-1,-1)};
        \addplot[blue!10] fill between[of=L1 and L2];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]